Navbar disappears after page refresh in Angular 17, with warnings about missing CSS files
I'm working with Angular 17, and I have a navbar in my UI that appears correctly after logging in. However, after refreshing the page, the navbar disappears. Additionally, I’m encountering the following warnings related to missing CSS files:
Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\Users\Nuthanapriya_Martha\NewCloning\appinsight\assets\css\material-icons\css\material-icons.min.css
Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\Users\Nuthanapriya_Martha\NewCloning\appinsight\assets\css\roboto.css
Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\Users\Nuthanapriya_Martha\NewCloning\appinsight\assets\css\MaterialIcons.css
Problem Details:
Navbar Behavior: The navbar appears when I log in, but after refreshing the page, it disappears.
Warnings: The above warnings related to missing CSS files are showing up. These files seem to be essential for styling the navbar with Material Icons and the Roboto font.
Steps I've Tried:
Checked paths: I’ve verified that the CSS file paths are correct and match the directory structure of my project.
Changed references: I’ve tried using both local paths and CDN links for the Material Icons and Roboto fonts, but the problem persists.
Login state management: I’ve ensured that the user is properly logged in, but the navbar only shows on the first login attempt and disappears after refreshing the page.
Questions:
Why does the navbar disappear after refreshing the page? I suspect it might be related to session persistence, or the authentication state might not be maintained across page refreshes.
How can I resolve the warnings about the missing CSS files? Is this due to incorrect file paths or a problem with how the files are being included in the project?
What changes do I need to make to ensure the navbar stays visible after a refresh? Should I be using session storage or local storage for authentication state, or is there a better way to handle this in Angular?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
